# How to limit the image file size on Directus?

Tags: directus

I want to limit the upload image size to 2MB so that images uploaded don't slow down the website's interface.

I tried adding into the image field a validation like so:

[image: example of filtering in directus]

Comment: It's probably the existing issue - https://github.com/directus/directus/issues/11775
https://github.com/directus/directus/issues/13140